Merging two pandas dataframe with repeated primary keys
I have two pandas dataframe that looks like
df1=
Class_ID    Student_ID  feature1
1           4             54
1           7             24
1           9             865
2           23            342
2           7             876
3           3             23
3           8             54
3           12            98
3           1             12

and
df2=
Class_ID    Student_ID  feature2
1           4             12
1           4             29
1           7             1
2           7             5
2           7             3
2           7             1
3           12            89
3           8             132
3           8             765
3           8             243
3           1             21
3           1             34

and I would like to merge the two dataframes on Class_ID, Student_ID. However, as one observes immediately, df2 have repeated primary keys, and i would like the outcome to be
Class_ID    Student_ID  feature1    feature2
1           4             54          12
1           4             54          29
1           7             24          1
1           9             865         nan
2           23            342         nan
2           7             876         5
2           7             876         3
2           7             876         1
3           3             23          nan
3           8             54          132
3           8             54          765
3           8             54          243
3           12            98          nan
3           1             12          21
3           1             12          34

I know about merge, join and concat but I don't seem to be able to get the result. Thank you so much in advance.

Use df1.merge(df2, on=['Class_ID','Student_ID'], how='outer')
